# How to remove specific column from the customer edit form view?

Tags: magento2, customer

I have this form with many columns.
I'd like to remove the specific column which is Enable Delivery Order Service.

In what kind of way I can achieve this?
[image: Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the relevant code for this in ***customer_index_edit.xml*** inside ***module-customer/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Customer::js/bootstrap/customer-post-action.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="admin.scope.col.wrap" htmlClass="admin__old" /><!-- ToDo UI: remove this wrapper with old styles removal. The class name "admin__old" is for tests only, we shouldn't use it in any way -->
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="customer_form"/> <!-- Responsible file for fields you need to modify -->
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Composite\Configure" name="after.body.start.product_composite_configure" template="Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/composite/configure.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In above file, you can find uiComponent, which can be found in ***module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml***, there find the field you want to remove and remove block related to the field you want to remove.

**Remember**, if the field is added by third-party module, you'll need to find the overriden files, although name of the files will be same.

Comment: It seems like the code is extended with unknown third party. Thank you for the answer @Natha Odedara